Convexifying a Non-Linear Fractional Function
I am working on a problem that involves a non-convex, non-linear fractional function:
$$
Y(X_1, X_2) = \frac{X_1 + X_2}{\alpha X_1 + \beta X_2}
$$
Where $X_{1}$, $X_{2}$, $Y$ are decision variables and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constant.
My goal is to find a way to reformulate this function as a convex or linear function. This would allow me to leverage powerful optimization techniques that are well-suited for convex problems.
Is there a known approach or technique to achieve convexification in this scenario? Perhaps a suitable approximation strategy that could transform the constraint into a convex or linear form?
